# Angular 6: How to use an array in template syntax with ngFor?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ngfor

I have two arrays: **books** and **booksDisplay**. In my template I use `*ngFor` to iterate through my `booksDisplay` array:

```
<div *ngFor="let bookDisplay of booksDisplay">
   <div class="book">
      <div class="title" *ngIf="???">{{ ???.title }}
   </div>
</div>
```

But inside my `*ngFor`-Element I need to look up in my `books`-Array, where `id` is equal to the current `bookId` in my `booksDisplay`-Array. So how can I use something like a where clause inside my `*ngFor`-Element?

Comment: You could create a dictionary/lookup property in your component where the key is the book id and reference that inside the `*ngFor` block. Or you can join the 2 arrays into one array and iterate over that.

Comment: In my opinion,  you should use method in the component.ts to filter those books then look up those books in the UI. Let the UI do the simple render will increase your performance.

Comment: could you please set an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcgx1h

Comment: Add your array's structure.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. However, I would better prepare data in a model instead of making such calculations in the template..

```
<div *ngFor="let bookDisplay of booksDisplay>
   <div class="book">
      <ng-container *ngIf="checkIfExist(bookDisplay.id)">
        <div class="title">{{ books[bookDisplay.id] }}
      </ng-container>
   </div>
</div>
```

Template:

```
checkIfExist(id: number) {
  return this.books.find( book => book['id'] === id ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your component.ts looks something like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
   booksDisplay = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'a'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'b'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'c'
    },
  ]
}
```

You can a counter to ngFor and use that value to filter on with ngIf conditional like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of booksDisplay; let i= index">
  <div class="book">
    <div class="title" *ngIf="i === book.id">{{ book.title }}
    </div>
    <p>{{i}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not work for me because the index isn't the book id. One book has more than one element in the booksDisplay array.... Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: I feel like I'm misunderstanding your question. Can you provide a small sample of the data that you are trying to sift through? I can edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like this; https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let book of booksDisplay; let i = index"> 
   <ng-container *ngIf="book.id === '1'">  
   <p> {{book.description}}</p>
</ng-container>
```